# Auto filter method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some code to filter and paste data from a table. Problem is I keep getting an "Auto filter method of range class failed with Criteria" error on this line:

```
 wsS1.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=tempCriteria
```

Can anyone point out what the problem is?

Thanks

```
Sub FilterBats()
    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsS2 As Worksheet
    Dim wsS3 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim tempCriteria As String


    Set wsS1 = Sheets("BallByBallBatting")
    Set wsS2 = Sheets("Summary")
    Set wsS3 = Sheets("FilteredBats")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastrow2 = wsS3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wsS3.Range("A1:N" & lastrow2).Delete

    tempCriteria = wsS2.Range("F3").Value

    wsS1.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=tempCriteria


        lastrow = wsS1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'
        wsS1.Range("A1:N" & lastrow).Copy wsS3.Range("A1")
        wsS1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What value does this range: `wsS2.Range("F3").Value` contain?

Comment: Hi Fane, it's a number

Comment: Can you let us know what number? Use `Debug.Print tempCriteria` before the line that troubled you. Since you assigned it to a `String` type variable it's effectively not a number btw. Btw, you shouldn't use `Cells`. Define a proper `Range` object. `Cells` uses the `UsedRange` which in your case might be throwing things off.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks. The print shows 8180 which is the number in F3

Comment: Instead of `wsS1.Cells.AutoFilter` try allocating a range, not all the cells... Something like that: `wsS1.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter`. On which row do you have the column headers?

Comment: Hi Fane, they’re on the first row

Comment: Define your last row, define your last column and **don't** use `Cells` to `AutoFilter`. Create your own `Range` object.

Comment: Did you adapt your line where the filter has been defined?  `wsS1.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter`...

Comment: Thanks guys. Fane your suggestion did the job. Thanks again

Comment: Glad being able to help... So, I will post an answer in those terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `wsS1.Cells.AutoFilter` try allocating a range, not using all the sheet cells...

Something like that: `wsS1.Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter` should work.

It will certainly work if the column headers are on the first row.